# How to Align Text Regardless of Number of Characters

Tags: css, reactjs, mantine

I have a CSS problem to align the texts in the top and bottom column regardless of the character size.

My problem is that the character size is different, so the texts are misaligned and I'm not finding a way to make them align.

Can you help me?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-maxwell-h8vin5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What do you mean by "align"?  left side, top side, right side, baseline? FWIW that sandbox has a LOT of rendered HTML to try to sort through...

Comment: I mean align the text of the two lines. For example, the texts "General Information" and "Main Address", need to be aligned at the top and bottom. If you notice, the "CEP" field is misaligned with the Registration Agency field.

Comment: Like "State" and "Complemento", they are misaligned with "Telephone" and "Legal Nature".

Comment: You DO realize that the linked sandbox is NOT in English so your comments are not of much use here - just restating things are not aligned makes nothing more clear - so do you mean the left side/start of the text, vertically aligned or what exactly.

Comment: Consider taking the rendered HTML and CSS (if there is any) and simplify it to the smallest possible example that reproduces your issue and put that as a snippet IN the question.

Comment: See, the Endereço Principal texts are not aligned with the Informações Gerais fields above.

I mean vertically. Note the discrepancy of texts in Endereço Principal, they are not aligned with Informações Gerais texts ABOVE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using grid is the best way to accomplish this because it allows you to control the layout in both directions -- horizontally and vertically.  With MantineUI, you can use the [`SimpleGrid`](https://mantine.dev/core/simple-grid/) component.

It's important to remember that each component in Mantine is associated with a specific set of CSS properties, so choosing a particular component has the purpose of applying those styles rather than organizing your code.  Below is an example of how you can remove the extraneous Mantine components to produce cleaner, more maintainable code and output. (Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-pasteur-cmk6cn?file=/src/App.js)).

```
//App.js
import { Fragment } from "react";
import {
  MantineProvider,
  Divider,
  Paper,
  SimpleGrid,
  Text,
  Title
} from "@mantine/core";
import { data } from "./data.js";

export default function App() {
  const breakpoints = [
    { maxWidth: "60rem", cols: 3, spacing: "md" },
    { maxWidth: "40rem", cols: 2, spacing: "sm" },
    { maxWidth: "30rem", cols: 1, spacing: "sm" }
  ];

  return (
    <MantineProvider withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS>
      <Paper shadow="xs" radius="xs" p="1rem" m="1rem">
        <Title order={2}>Conta</Title>
        <Text size="sm" color="violet-purple.0" fw={700} mb="lg">
          Restaurante Vila do Fausto Ltda
        </Text>
        <Divider size="xs" variant="dotted" />
        {data.map((section) => (
          <Fragment key={section.title}>
            <Title order={5} my="lg">
              {section.title}
            </Title>
            <SimpleGrid cols={4} spacing="lg" mb="lg" breakpoints={breakpoints}>
              {section.content.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.heading}>
                  <Text color="#7C9599" fw={700} size="sm">
                    {item.heading}:
                  </Text>
                  <Text size="0.8rem">{item.details}</Text>
                </div>
              ))}
            </SimpleGrid>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </Paper>
    </MantineProvider>
  );
}


//data.js
export const data = [
  {
    title: "Informações Gerais",
    content: [
      { heading: "Nome da Empresa", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "CPF / CNPJ", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Razão Social ", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "E-mail", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Telefone", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Natureza Jurídica", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "NIRE", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Orgão de Registro ", details: "Lorem Ipsum" }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Endereço Principal",
    content: [
      { heading: "Logradouro", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Número", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Bairro", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Cidade", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Estado", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "Complemento", details: "Lorem Ipsum" },
      { heading: "CEP", details: "Lorem Ipsum" }
    ]
  }
];
```